# Change axises' scale in a plot without creating new varibale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset like below (this is only the first 20 rows and the first 3 columns of data):

```
row fitted  measured
1   1866    1950
2   2489    2500
3   1486    1530
4   1682    1720
5   1393    1402
6   2524    2645
7   2676    2789
8   3200    3400
9   1455    1456
10  1685    1765
11  2587    2597
12  3040    3050
13  2767    2769
14  3300    3310
15  4001    4050
16  1918    2001
17  2889    2907
18  2063    2150
19  1591    1640
20  3578    3601
```

I plotted this data

```
plot(data$measured~data$fitted, ylab = expression("Measured Length (" * mu ~ "m)"),
     xlab = expression("NIR Fitted Length (" * mu ~ "m)"), cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5)
```

and got the following:

[image]

As you can see the axises scales are in micrometer, I need the axis to be in millimeter.

How can I plot the data while axises are in millimeter, WITHOUT creating a new variable?

Like this;

[image]

If I want to create a new variable, I have to change the whole 2000 lines code that I've written before and that's not a road that I want to go! :|

Thanks much :)

Comment: Just divide by 1000 and change axis labels: `plot(y=data$measure / 1000, x=data$fitted / 1000, ylab = "Measured Length (mm)",
     xlab = "NIR Fitted Length (mm)")`

Comment: Or, if you wanna stick to formula, I guess you can use `I(data$measure/1000)~I(data$fitted/1000)`. See `?AsIs`. A 3rd option could be to use custom labels by omitting axes on `plot` and using `axis` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. @IukeA method worked better

Comment: Post it as a solution then. Might help someone someday. You went to all that work already.

Answer (score 1):

I used @bdemarest method for plot and @IukeA method for `abline` ;

```
plot(y=data$measured/1000,x=data$fitted/1000, ylab = expression("Measured Length (mm)"),
     xlab = expression("NIR Fitted Length (mm)"), cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5)


 a = lm(I(data$measured/1000)~I(data$fitted/1000), data=data)
    abline(a)
```

Here is the final plot;

[image]